# How do I remove reboot, halt and shutdown privileges using visudo?

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo

I am trying to take reboot privileges away from the user Rick. I have tried both `!` and `NOEXEC`. Is there another way to do this?

```
Rick   ALL = (ALL)  !/sbin/reboot
Rick   ALL = NOEXEC: /sbin/reboot
```

Comment: Instead focus on giving limited commands. If Rick is known to abuse privileges, give access only to wrapper scripts that must sanitize user input.

Comment: Why does Rick need sudo at all? What sudo-using things does he need that you trust him with those things, but not to reboot? Does he need to be able to modify any file in the filesystem? Or update system libraries? It sounds like maybe you need more permissions that are more specific to the things that Rick actually needs to do, and you should restrict Rick to those things.

Comment: I once worked at a place where the (uneducated) Linux sysadmins had created a "negative sudo" for users. Their list of denied commands was hundred of lines long and attempted to include *all combinations of text editors and system files*: `/bin/vi /etc/passwd`, `/bin/nano /etc/passwd`, `/bin/vi /etc/networks`, `/bin/nano /etc/networks`, and so on. I did not last long at that job.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. It is practically impossible to create a "negative sudo" to assign an user the right to run any command except some. This because the user can bypass these restrictions easily, e.g.

- by inserting the denied command into a shell script and run it
- by copying the denied command to a different name
- by running a similar command (in your case `init 6`, `telinit 6`, `shutdown -r now`, and `systemctl isolate reboot.target` will all perform a reboot and are not denied commands)
- by running the denied command via `exec`
- by escaping a shell from a text editor or another program
- or simply by switching to the root user via `su`

This is also said in the `sudoers` manpage:

```
SECURITY NOTES
   Limitations of the ‘!’ operator
     It is generally not effective to “subtract” commands from ALL 
     using the ‘!’ operator.  A user can trivially circumvent this by copy-
     ing the desired command to a different name and then executing that.  
     For example:

     bill    ALL = ALL, !SU, !SHELLS

     Doesn’t really prevent bill from running the commands listed in SU
     or SHELLS since he can simply copy those commands to a different
     name, or use a shell escape from an editor or other program.  
     Therefore, these kind of restrictions should be considered advisory at
     best (and reinforced by policy).

     In general, if a user has sudo ALL there is nothing to prevent 
     them from creating their own program that gives them a root shell (or
     making their own copy of a shell) regardless of any ‘!’ elements 
     in the user specification.
```

Instead, you should identify a restricted set of commands necessary to the user and give only access to these commands.

`NOEXEC` just disables shell escapes and will not protect against all other circumvention methods.

Comment: Also switch to root and exec the command :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov True, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Without `sudo` at all the user still has a simple if inelegant hardware solution, so software controls aren't going to be very effective.  The true solution to the underlying problem may be a matter for workplace.se or interpersonal.se.

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, if the user has access to the hardware or e.g. the hypervisor of the VM. In this case denying the user access to the `reboot` command is a moot point ;)

Comment: @dr_ I must admit I forgot that hardware access was an assumption rather than guaranteed, because I've rarely used systems without it, and those were mainly Windows or servers where I had limited permissions anyway